# variable string won't get give me a length

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables

So i'm using javascript to help me make a simple personality quiz. Easy right?
I'm having one problem. On the final question I get java to grab an ID called "finalPage" and then I have an if statement for it checking that it indeed does say "finalPage". Weirdly it assumes that its wrong. I've also tried getting the word length and matching it with a number but to no avail. Here's the code. 
I've also checked to make sure the words match. I have no idea whats going on.

Html:

```
        <div id="finalQuestion" data-next="finalPage">
            <h2> Question 10, Once you finish do this again! </h2>
                <h3> Pick the best Genre </h3>
                    <div class="button" data-group="Keyboard"> Thriller </div>
                    <div class="button" data-group="Brass"> Comedy </div>
                    <div class="button" data-group="Woodwind"> Romance </div>
                    <div class="button" data-group="Guitar"> Action </div>
                    <div class="button" data-group="Percussion"> Horror </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div id="finalPage">
        <div id="GuitarPage">
            <h2> Congratulations! You will be turned into a...</h2>
                <h1> Guitar Instrument! </h1>
                    <!-- insert image -->


        </div>

        <div id="BrassPage">
            <h2> Congratulations! You will be turned into a...</h2>
                <h1> Brass Instrument! </h1>
                    <!-- insert image -->


        </div>

        <div id="WoodwindPage">
            <h2> Congratulations! You will be turned into a...</h2>
                <h1> Woodwind Instrument! </h1>
                    <!-- insert image -->


        </div>

        <div id="PercussionPage">
            <h2> Congratulations! You will be turned into a...</h2>
                <h1> Percussion Instrument! </h1>
                    <!-- insert image -->


        </div>
        <div id="KeyboardPage">
            <h2> Congratulations! You will be turned into a...</h2>
                <h1> Keyboard Instrument! </h1>
                    <!-- insert image -->


        </div>
    </div>
```

Heres the Javascript:

```
var thispage = this.parentElement;
thispage.style.display = "none";

var nextQuestion= document.getElementById( thispage.dataset.next );
if (nextQuestion == "finalPage") 
{
    if(Guitar > Percussion && Brass && Keyboard && Woodwind)
        {
        document.getElementById("Guitar").style.display ="none";
        }

        if(Percussion > Guitar && Brass && Keyboard && Woodwind) 
        {
            document.getElementById("Percussion").style.display ="none";

        }

    if(Brass > Percussion && Guitar && Keyboard && Woodwind) {
        document.getElementById("Brass").style.display ="none";
    }

    if(Keyboard > Percussion && Guitar && Brass && Woodwind) {
        document.getElementById("Keyboard").style.display ="none";
    }

    if(Woodwind > Percussion && Guitar && Keyboard && Brass) {
        document.getElementById("Woodwind").style.display ="none";
    }
    //show final page
}

else {
    nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Comment: You are trying to compare `document.getElementById()` with a string. Maybe you want to pull the id out and compare that? Maybe not since you use that id to make the getById call... Not sure what you are even trying to do.

Comment: Doesn't document.getElementByID (when I turn it into a variable) doesn't that become a string?

Comment: I'm trying to get one of the 5 pages to show if the document.getElementByID is "finalPage"

Comment: "_Doesn't document.getElementByID (when I turn it into a variable) doesn't that become a string?_" No. Do something like `alert(nextQuestion)` after your getById and you will see that it does not print a string. It returns/prints an entire element. You didn't say get the id of the element, you said get the element. If you want the id add .id to the end of the getById. But as I said before, that would be useless since _you already have the id in thispage.dataset.next_.

Comment: Yeah ok. So how do i get thispage.dataset.next to become a string? or at least be able to use it in that if statement?

Comment: That already is a string I bet. You used it as one in your getById call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a DOM element, not it's id. If you'd like to know if the element you've grabbed has an id of "finalPage", you'd have to check it explicitly:

```
if (nextQuestion.getAttribute('id') === 'finalPage') {

   // ...

}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. 
Is there a way to grab that element and turn it into a string?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "turn it into a string." DOM Elements are complicated and have many, many properties including its position, style, several manipulative functions, etc. The answer I posted is how to retrieve the id of the element as a string. If it's not working, then perhaps the DOM Element you received is undefined, or doesn't have an id attribute. Are you sure that `this.dataset.next` has the value you're expecting? Try stepping through a debugger or outputting some logging lines (such as `console.log(this.dataset.next)` and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah I went through chrome's debugger and it said that nextQuestion had an Id="finalPage" 
for your code should i put something in other than 'id'?

Comment: It's difficult to advise on what might be happening here, since I'm not entirely sure what your code is trying to do. Looking over your code more closely, it appears that you already know the element's id (since you get the element by its id in the first place using the value stored in this.dataset.next), so getting the element's id attribute would only give you a value you already know. What, exactly, are you hoping to test for when you say `if nextQuestion == 'finalPage'`?

Comment: Oh, so when this.dataset.next is "finalPage" I want to be able, depending on their answers, open up a particular div like the Keyboard div for example.

Comment: Is `this.dataset.next` a DOM element? If so, you can compare its id with `if (this.dataset.next.getAttribute('id') === 'finalPage')`. If it's a string, on the other hand, then you can simply test `if (this.dataset.next == 'finalPage')` without having to get the element at all.

Comment: I'm assuming its a DOM element. It's grabbing an ID from html. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Stop assuming. Use alerts, logs, or the debugger and find out for sure. Guessing is no good.

Comment: Takendarkk I really don't appreciate your negative tone towards me. Also I would like to point out you didn't actually help me but just told me I was stupid ( in a very clever way, bravo)

Comment: Thanks Mark that worked! Although my if statements for the guitar > keyboard....etc isn't but that's an easy fix. Thanks again